# What does void() mean when used as a template parameter?

Tags: c++

I am struggling to find an answer to this question mainly because *I don't know how I would look it up* as there are no relative search-terms or concepts I can think of. It is an unusual syntax to my eyes.

In the following code, what does  **void()** mean?

```
std::deque<std::function<void()>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void()` is the type of a function that takes no arguments and has `void` return type. An object of type `std::function<void()>` is therefore an object you can call with no arguments, which will return no value when called.

Comment: So the name can be omitted?  Also, I feel overwhelmed over function syntax.  Is there a good resource that shows all the ways a particular function signature can by denoted in a parameter list?

Comment: @jakeliquorblues you don't use a name when writing down a type, only when declaring variables.

Comment: @jakeliquorblues It's just all the ways you would write a function declaration but without the function name in it.

Comment: Just a little sidenote here: `void` as a type is also often used in conunction with type traits to "undefine" templates.

Comment: @jakeliquorblues: `int x;` declares an object; `int` is the name of that object. `void foo();` declares a function; `void()` is the type of that function. Same principle.